# Specify Relative location of images

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Some fun stuff happened this morning at work. We don't have a backup for our Wordpress site and a user updated the theme. We are using Atahualpa 3.7.12 and upgraded to 3.7.14. Soon after the update, the images were lost and started displaying some default ones.

My images have this form

```
http://<website>/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Tractor.png
http://<website>/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/home-header.png
```

but when I look in the debugger I see it points to

```
http://<website>/wp-content/themes/atahualpa/images/2013/06/Tractor.png
```

I have no experience with Wordpress and trying to restore the images. I am looking at

```
Atahualpa Theme Options -> Image Location -> Relative location of images which has the Default.
```

I changed it to the following:

```
Relative location of images? wp-content (which is the only other option in the dropdown)
Images Directory to uploads but the image is still not showing up.
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try is resaving permalinks. Goto Settings >> Permalinks and hit save. Sometimes resaving these helps. Not a guaranteed solution here, but worth a try.

Alternatively, after playing with the settings in Atahulpa Theme Options you should go to your site to one of the pages that has missing themes. Using Google Chrome, right click the image and hit Inspect Element. This will show the HTML for the path that is is trying to point to. You can then see if your settings in theme options is getting you anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the Chrome debugger tip. That helped me get a step further.